# Trying to get image views arranged in a grid type layout

Tags: android, layout

I want to have a grid type layout of image views. To begin i tried to see if I could get this using simple buttons.
This is easy enough where I can create an array of buttons using linear layouts but the problem arises when I try to use an imageView instead of a button.
Is there an easy way to force android to fit the imageView in the exact same space a button fits in.
Image view seems to ignore the width weight?  I don't mind if the aspect ratio of the pic gets distorted but ideally it 
would keep this ratio and just shrink the image till it fits exactly.  What is the best way to get this working?

Here is my current xml.......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="4" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/chicken" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try using android:scaleType = "fitXY" for your ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using weight/weightsum parameters in your linearlayout, you might want to set your height (if linearlayout is vertical) or width (if linearlayout is horizontal) to 0dip instead of fill_parent. that way your layout_weight distribution will be computed correctly. this wouldn't matter if you're using equal weights (1), but you will notice the difference when trying to assign different weights for different children inside your linearlayout.

for imageviews, you can check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html%20link) for the different imageview scaletypes. you will be needing FIT_XY for this specific purpose.

Comment: Yes,  that has worked for me.  The example is very similar to the one in the book "Beginning Android Development" I am reading at the moment. I'm just very surprised there is no easier way to implement a UI like this than having to do it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the gridlayout used in photostream app from Romain Guy. It lays out child views in equal sized cells based on number of rows and columns. [Here is source code](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Photostream/src/com/google/android/photostream/GridLayout.java).

It will look something like this in the xml file

```
<com.blessan.dashboard.GridLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!--Child views go here-->
</com.blessan.dashboard.GridLayout>
```

You will need to specify the number of rows and columns.